# jQuery - addClass not working

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I've got the following HTML :

```
<div class="b-250">
  <div id="c6281_701_1" class="sam-container sam-place" data-sam="1">
    <a id="a55_701" class="sam_ad" target="_blank" href="XYZ">
      <img alt="" src="XYZ">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>

<script>
    jQuery(document).ready(function(){
        console.log('try it - window ready');
        //jQuery('div.sam_ad').find('img').addClass('wp-post-image article-  thumbnail');
        console.log(jQuery(".b-250").find('div'));
        jQuery(".b-250").find('div').addClass("home-post has-post-thumbnail post");
        console.log('did it - window ready');
    });
</script>
```

I cannot manage to add some Classes to the element with class `sam_ad` .

I tried it in different Ways like `jQuery('.sam_ad')...` or the above.

Any Clue?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using:

`jQuery(".sam_ad").addClass("home-post has-post-thumbnail post");`

Instead of:

`jQuery(".b-250").find('div').addClass("home-post has-post-thumbnail post");`

should work just fine.

In this [example filddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Uwcuz/2813/), it adds the classes:

```
<a id="a55_701" class="sam_ad home-post has-post-thumbnail post" target="_blank" href="XYZ">
```

Make sure you have included the jQuery library

---

If you are using Wordpress (as it seems you are), you may need to wrap you jQuery in a document ready function:

```
 jQuery(document).ready(function() {        
    console.log('try it - window ready');
    jQuery(".sam_ad").addClass("home-post has-post-thumbnail post");
    console.log('did it - window ready');
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your answer which is, in normal context, working well.

I found out that there is some strange ajax-request working which renders the .sam_ad-Object. So the default document.ready-function did not apply to the objects, because they weren't rendered at the moment when the dom was ready.

so i switched to window.load, which works fine ..

Answer (score 0):

Just update your jQuery version into 1.12 or later

```
function modify_js_cdn() {
    if ( ! is_admin() ) {
        // comment out the next two lines to load the local copy of jQuery
        wp_deregister_script( 'jquery' );
        wp_register_script( 'jquery', 'http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js', false, '1.12.4' );
        wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery' );
    }
}

add_action( 'init', 'modify_js_cdn' );
```